# Looping over an array of inputs with the same name

Tags: php, arrays

I'm making a todo list and I've got everything working except for this one thing. I need to loop over inputs that's been submitted via a form, these inputs have the same name so what I've done is storing them as an array. Now I need to loop over them so I can send them into the database one by one. Here's what I tried:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $labelValues = $_POST['labelValue[]'];

    $i = 0;

    while($i < sizeof($labelValues)) {

        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tenta_table (text) VALUES (:text)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':text', $labelValues[$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $i++;
    }
}
```

HTML, the inputs are marked with red:

[image: inputs]

But it doesn't seem to work, it's not giving me any errors so I have nothing to go on. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Can you post your HTML part where this post value came ?

Comment: Not Sure, but as far as i remember it should be `$labelValues = $_POST['labelValue']`. I think your `$labelValues` is `null` and you don't even enter your loop. You should do a `var_dump( $_POST )` to verify what you're working with.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi added picture.

Comment: @evilive holy tennis shoes, it actually worked to do that! thanks! :D post as an asnwer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$_POST['labelValue']` will already be an array if you have named your inputs correctly, something like `<input type="text" name="labelValue[]" />` would create and array called labelValue in your POST.

From there you should be able to use your current code with one minor change

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $labelValues = $_POST['labelValue'];

    $i = 0;

    while($i < sizeof($labelValues)) {

        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tenta_table (text) VALUES (:text)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':text', $labelValues[$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Above I have change `$labelValues` to equal `$_POST['lableValue']` rather than `$_POST['labelValue[]']`

Answer (score 1):

In your case only the last input element will be available.

If you want multiple inputs with the same name use `name="foo[]"` for the input name attribute. `$_POST` will then contain an array for foo with all values from the input elements.

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="a[]" value="foo"/>
    <input name="a[]" value="bar"/>
    <input name="a[]" value="baz"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The reason why `$_POST` will only contain the last value if you don't use `[]` is because PHP will basically just explode and foreach over the raw query string to populate `$_POST`. When it encounters a name/value pair that already exists, it will overwrite the previous one.

However, you can still access the raw query string like this:

```
$rawQueryString = file_get_contents('php://input'))
```

Assuming you have a form like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="foo"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="bar"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="baz"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

the $`rawQueryString` will then contain `a=foo&a=bar&a=baz`.

You can then use your own logic to parse this into an array. A naive approach would be

```
$post = array();
foreach (explode('&', file_get_contents('php://input')) as $keyValuePair) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $keyValuePair);
    $post[$key][] = $value;
}
```

which would then give you an array of arrays for each name in the query string.

or the best and simple approach for this

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="a[0]" value="foo"/>
    <input name="a[1]" value="bar"/>
    <input name="a[2]" value="baz"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
$labelValues = $_POST['labelValue[]'];
```

By

```
$labelValues = $_POST['labelValue'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure, but as far as i remember it should be $labelValues = $_POST['labelValue']. I think your $labelValues is null and you don't even enter your loop. You should do a var_dump( $_POST ) to verify what you're working with.